# Error "Misplaced &" in Mathjax

Tags: errors, vertical-alignment

I'm rendering the following code in Mathjax:

```
$$\begin{aligned} \|f(a+h)-f(a) - Ah \|

&=\left \|\sum_{k=1}^{n} h_{k} \int_{0}^{1} \left(\partial_{k} f\left(x_{k-1}+t h_{k} e_{k}\right) -\partial_{k} f(a)\right) d t \right \| \\

&\le \sum_{k=1}^{n} |h_{k}|  \int_{0}^{1} \left \| \partial_{k} f\left(x_{k-1}+t h_{k} e_{k}\right) -\partial_{k} f(a)\right \| d t \\

&\le |h|_\infty \sum_{k=1}^{n}   \int_{0}^{1} \left \| \partial_{k} f\left(x_{k-1}+t h_{k} e_{k}\right) -\partial_{k} f(a)\right \| d t \\

&\le |h|_\infty \sum_{k=1}^{n}   \int_{0}^{1} \sup_{t \in [0,1]} \left \| \partial_{k} f\left(x_{k-1}+t h_{k} e_{k}\right) -\partial_{k} f(a) \| d t \\ 

&\le |h|_\infty \sum_{k=1}^{n}   \int_{0}^{1}  \sup_{x \in \mathbb{B}(a, \|h\|_\infty)} \left \| \partial_{k} f\left(x\right) -\partial_{k} f(a)\right \| d t \\

&= |h|_\infty \sum_{k=1}^{n}  \sup_{x \in \mathbb{B}(a, \|h\|_\infty)} \left \| \partial_{k} f\left(x\right) -\partial_{k} f(a)\right \|\end{aligned}$$
```

I could not understand why "Misplaced &" appears in Mathjax, but this code is rendered well in my LaTex editor.

> [image]

Could you please help me figure out where is the error in my code? Thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome! You should remove the empty lines and add a `\right` before the second `\|` in `&\le |h|_\infty \sum_{k=1}^{n}   \int_{0}^{1} \sup_{t \in [0,1]} \left \| \partial_{k} f\left(x_{k-1}+t h_{k} e_{k}\right) -\partial_{k} f(a) \| d t \\`, but this site is not on MathJax (I think).

Comment: Thank you so much @Schrödinger'scat :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to fixing the two obvious issues which @Schrödinger'scat already pointed out (the inappropriate blank lines and a missing `\right` qualifier), you may want to get rid of all `\left` and `\right` sizing qualifiers: they either don't and shouldn't increase the size of the fences; in the one lone case in which the fence size *should* be increased, they don't do the job.

Here's how I'd rewrite your six-line equation in a LaTeX (not mathjax) setting.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{split} 
\norm{f(a+h) - f(a) - Ah}
&= \norm[\bigg]{\sum_{k=1}^{n} h_{k} \int_{0}^{1} \bigl(\partial_{k} f(x_{k-1}+t h_{k} e_{k}) -\partial_{k} f(a)\bigr) \,dt} \\
&\le \sum_{k=1}^{n} \abs{h_{k}} \int_{0}^{1} \norm{\partial_{k} f(x_{k-1}+t h_{k} e_{k}) -\partial_{k} f(a)} \,dt \\
&\le \abs{h}_\infty \sum_{k=1}^{n} \int_{0}^{1} \norm{\partial_{k} f(x_{k-1}+t h_{k} e_{k}) -\partial_{k} f(a)} \,dt \\
&\le \abs{h}_\infty \sum_{k=1}^{n} \int_{0}^{1} \!\sup_{t\in[0,1]} \norm{\partial_{k} f(x_{k-1}+t h_{k} e_{k}) -\partial_{k} f(a)} \,dt \\ 
&\le \abs{h}_\infty \sum_{k=1}^{n} \int_{0}^{1} \!\sup_{x\in\mathbb{B}(a,\norm{h}_\infty)} \norm{\partial_{k} f(x) -\partial_{k} f(a)} \,dt \\
&= \abs{h}_\infty \sum_{k=1}^{n} \sup_{x\in\mathbb{B}(a,\norm{h}_\infty)} \norm{\partial_{k} f(x) -\partial_{k} f(a)}
\end{split}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: @Akira - Incidentally, I noticed that you write `|h|_\infty` in four instances and `\|h\|_\infty` in two others. Is this intentional?

Comment: Oh my bad, it's a typo :(. I meant `|h|_\infty`.